# Amazon's suggested Cloudformation template for EKS VPC setup directly contradicts its recommendations. Does another template exist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

In the article [Getting Started with Amazon EKS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html), it recommends creating a VPC for the cluster using [this](https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2019-02-11/amazon-eks-vpc-sample.yaml) provided cloudformation template. That template creates a VPC with three public subnets and 0 private subnets.

In the article [Cluster VPC Considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html) it says

> We recommend a network architecture that uses private subnets for your worker nodes and public subnets for Kubernetes to create internet-facing load balancers within

Does a cloudformation template exist anywhere that is actually in line with their own recommendations?

Comment: There is an eks cloudformation sample with public and private subnets now at https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation/2019-01-09/amazon-eks-vpc-private-subnets.yaml

Answer (score 0):

The [Cluster VPC Considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html) document is only to provide recommendation and guidelines and the real architecture implementation depends on your requirements. If you are looking into creating a private and public subnet on a VPC, there is a sample of cloudformation template : [Sample template](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/blob/master/aws/services/VPC/VPC_With_Managed_NAT_And_Private_Subnet.yaml)  that you can use to help you to get started writing your own template.

EKS cluster can be created on an existing VPC either using existing subnets or new subnets as long as it fulfils the requirements listed on the VPC consideration : [Cluster VPC Considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html) , such as tagging for internal load balancer, VPC DNS hostname and DNS resolution support. When creating an EKS cluster, you can pick any VPC and subnets (within the VPC) in the region : Getting Started with Amazon EKS - Step 1: [Create Your Amazon EKS Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started.html#eks-create-cluster) and it doesn’t have to be the one created by cloudformation.